# Kendo Grid MVC - DataSource Error

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm just starting to learn Kendo UI MVC and am running across the following issue. Here is my code:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<JeffreysOnline.Entities.Customer>()
    .Name("grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.FirstName);
        columns.Bound(p => p.LastName);
        columns.Bound(p => p.Address);
        columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); command.Destroy(); }).Width(250);
    })
    .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create())
    .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
    .Scrollable()
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:550px;" })
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .PageSize(20)
        .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
        .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.ProductID))
        .Create(update => update.Action("EditingInline_Create", "Grid"))
        .Read(read => read.Action("EditingInline_Read", "Grid"))
        .Update(update => update.Action("EditingInline_Update", "Grid"))
        .Destroy(update => update.Action("EditingInline_Destroy", "Grid"))
    )
)
```

I'm getting the following error, with line 23 highlighted.

```
Compiler Error Message: CS1660: Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type

Line 21:     .Scrollable()
Line 22:     .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:550px;" })
Line 23:     .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
Line 24:         .Ajax()
Line 25:         .PageSize(20)
```

It appears it doesn't like 'dataSource' but I have no clue what it would be expecting.

Comment: I would suggest you to debug this by commenting each line of the data source individually and testing it that way, you may be able to more effectively identify which line of code is specifically causing your problem. Honestly, I'd start with commenting out the Update, Destroy and Create lines. If your grid can't first read the data, it sure as heck can't do any of those other methods either!

Comment: Can you provide code example of your model object? Is ProductId actually a property in your object? the model declaration within the Datasource may be the issue if that property doesn't exist! I reckon ProductId is the Id used in example http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/editing-inline that it looks like you've started from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If ProductId is not a property of your model, this may be causing the error.

It appears you took the example almost directly from telerik's inline editing tutorial page at: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/editing-inline, so try adjusting the column this is pointing to for your Model within the data source. like so:

```
 .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .PageSize(20)
        .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
        .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.RandyMindersActualIdColumnProperty)) // Here is the change
        .Create(update => update.Action("EditingInline_Create", "Grid"))
        .Read(read => read.Action("EditingInline_Read", "Grid"))
        .Update(update => update.Action("EditingInline_Update", "Grid"))
        .Destroy(update => update.Action("EditingInline_Destroy", "Grid"))
    )
```

Comment: Yes, this was the problem. The code is now running but shouldn't the EditingInline_Read method get called when the page loads? It's not and so no data is displayed in the grid.

Comment: If you add debug breakpoints into your controller method is it not being hit?  If you open your browsers dev tools do you see any javascript errors when this event should occur?  Is your controller named Grid and actually called "EditingInline_Read"? Can you provide example of your controller code? :)